# Joomla Component 2.5 data from model to view QUERY trouble

Tags: joomla, components

I am developing a Joomla Component 2.5 and at the moment I am stuck on retrieving data from my model. I'm using the following query to retrieve the data:

**In my model:**

```
    public function test() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query ->select(array('desc')) ->from('PC_APIData');

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $results = $db->loadObjectstdClass();

}
```

**in my view.html.php:**

```
    $InternetModelInternet = &$this->getModel('Internet');
    $test = $InternetModelInternet->test();
    $getData = $InternetModelInternet->getData();

    var_dump($getData);
```

The only way I can retrieve the data is to use vardump it shows me the data I need. But how can I resolve this in a return or echo? Cause when I use one of these the result is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your model.

```
 public function test() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query ->select(array('desc')) ->from('PC_APIData');

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $results = $db->loadObjectstdClass(); 
     //loadObjectList,loadObject or any other methods you can use for fetching based on list or single row. any way the result return as array.
    return $result;


    }
```

In your view

```
 $InternetModelInternet = &$this->getModel('Internet');
 $test = $InternetModelInternet->test();
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($test).
```

The result should be array may be list or single based on your query condition.

Any way you should return the result from model then only you will get it in the view or controller.
For more details of Joomla db query [look here](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/2.5#The_Query)

Also you can write query like this.

```
 $db = JFactory::getDbo();
 $sql ="your detailed query";
 $db->setQuery($sql);
 $db->query();
 $res = $db->loadObjectList();
 return $res;
```

Hope this may help you..

Comment: It deffintly helped, but my output looks like a array, you know the way to convert it? I tried a foreach but than it gaves me error that he can't read the foreach

Comment: foreach will work , whcih option is using object list or assoclist ? based on that foreach $value[''] this for asssoc list  access change $vaule->key for objectlist